# Error in using templates in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, header-files, avl-tree

I want to implement an AVL Tree using templates in C++. The header file, C++ file and the main file are as below :

AVLTree.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace MYTree
{
    template <class T>
    class AVLTree
    {
        public:
            struct AVLNode
            {
                struct AVLNode *left;
                struct AVLNode *right;
                struct AVLNode *parent;
                int balanceFactor;
            };

            //Constructor
            AVLTree();
            //Variables
            AVLNode *root;
            //Methods
            AVLNode<T> *lookup(const T &key);
            AVLNode<T> *insert(const T &key);
            void remove(const T &key);
    };
}
```

AVLTree.cpp

```
#include "AVLTree.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
AVLTree<T>::AVLTree()
{
    cout <<"HI\n";
}


template <class T>
AVLNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::lookup(const T &key)
{
}

template <class T>
AVLNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::insert(const T &key)
{
}

template <class T>
void AVLTree<T>::remove(const T &key)
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "AVLTree.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AVLTree<int> tree();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the main.cpp, I get the following errors :

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
AVLTree.h:27: error: `MyTree::Node' is not a template
AVLTree.h:28: error: `MyTree::Node' is not a template
AVLTree.h:30: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

**Edit :**

```
main.cpp:9: error: `AVLTree' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:9: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
main.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before "int"
main.cpp:9: error: expected `;' before "int"
```

I am using templates for the very first time. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVLNode` isn't a template; it's a regular class nested within a template. So within the template, just use the class name:

```
AVLNode *lookup(const T &key);
```

and outside the template, qualify it with the template's scope:

```
template <class T>
AVLTree<T>::AVLNode* AVLTree<T>::lookup(const T &key)
{
}
```

You'll also need to fix the definition of `AVLNode`; you're currently declaring `Node` to be a data member of `AVLTree` (which you don't want), and attempt to define a type `AVLNode` to be an alias for `Node` (which won't compile since `Node` isn't a type). Just define a class type, with no data members or typedefs:

```
struct AVLNode
{
    AVLNode *left;
    AVLNode *right;
    AVLNode *parent;
    int balanceFactor;
};
```

As noted in the comments, templates (including member functions of class templates) usually need to be defined in a header, as the definition must be available wherever it's used.

You'll also need to make sure the definitions are in the correct namespace, and qualify the template name appropriately (`MYTree::AVLNode`) when you're not in that namespace.

`AVLTree<int> tree();` declares a function; remove the `()` to create a default-initialised object.

Finally, don't do `using namespace std;` in the global namespace, as it can lead to confusing name conflicts.

Comment: +1, but you could also mention [the inability to implement templates in source files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465).

Comment: @Angew: Good point, I didn't notice that it was in a source file.

Comment: I followed your answer and the template errors are gone. But there are some errors in main.cpp. Please see the edit in errors.

Comment: @Hellboy: `AVLTree` is in a namespace, so you'll need to qualify it as `MYTree::AVLTree` when you're not in that namespace.

Comment: @Mike, How should I declare an object in main.cpp ?
Using MYTree::AVLTree<int> tree() is wrong and using MyTree::AVLTree<int> tree gives a compilation error :
undefined reference to `MyTree::AVLTree<int>::AVLTree()'

Comment: @Hellboy: Indeed, with the `()` it declares a function, which is not what you want. It should be `MYTree::AVLTree<int> tree;`. Note the capitalisation of `MYTree` - that must match the namespace name.

Comment: Oh..Capitalisation is not a problem. I wrote it wrong here. Declaring an object like the latter still gives an error.

Comment: @Hellboy: It sounds like the definition of the default constructor is missing - did you move that into the header with the other members?

Comment: I had to implement the methods in the header file as suggested by Vlad. So, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This typedef

```
       typedef struct Node AVLNode;
```

is invalid. First of all you have no defined structure Node and secondly this typedef hides declaration of name `struct AVLnode`

It shall be removed. The error messages are results of this typedef because in this declarations

```
        AVLNode<T> *lookup(const T &key);
        AVLNode<T> *insert(const T &key);
```

you specified  name `AVLNode` as a template name.

Nevertheless your code contains other errors. Template member functions have to be placed in the same header file where the template class is defined. Otherwise you will get linker errors that references are undefined.

This statement in main

```
AVLTree<int> tree();
```

is not a definition of an object. It is a function declaration that has return type `AVLTree<int>` and has no parameters.

Comment: AVLTree<int> tree() doesn't give a compilation error. However, "HI" is not printed which should be printed from the constructor.

Comment: @Hellboy It does not issue a compilation error because the construction is a valid function declaration. So neither constructor is called.

Comment: If I write AVLTree<int> tree; , it causes this error :
undefined reference to `MyTree::AVLTree<int>::AVLTree()'

Comment: @Hellboy I wrote in my post that member function definitions shall be included in the header where the template class is defined.

Comment: So, that means I have to implement the method in the AVLTree.h file itself?

Answer (score 0):

you use `AVLNode<T>` but `AVLNode` is not a template, as the message say.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
struct AVLnode
{
    ...
}Node;
```

you declare a *member variable* named `Node`.

When you later do

```
typedef struct Node AVLNode;
```

you try to use the member variable as a structure.

Remember that you are programming C++, where structure names can be used as types just the same as class names.

You also try to use `AVLNode` as a template in e.g.

```
AVLNode<T> *lookup(const T &key);
```

But just as the error messages says, the `AVLNode` structure is not a templated structure.